# How to calculate average of identified item in array?

Tags: mongodb

My data sample, I'm using bucket to group because to data of a month or day, and `{ out: { minMathPoint: { $min: '$result.0.point' }}}` not working.

```
[{
  name: 'studen_a',
  results: [{
    subject: 'Math',
    point: 9,
  }, {
    subject: 'Physical',
    point: 10,
  }]
}, {
  name: 'studen_b',
  results: [{
    subject: 'Math',
    point: 8,
  }, {
    subject: 'Physical',
    point: 8,
  }]
}, {
  name: 'studen_c',
  results: [{
    subject: 'Math',
    point: 10,
  }, {
    subject: 'Physical',
    point: 8,
  }]
}, {
  name: 'studen_d',
  results: [{
    subject: 'Math',
    point: 9,
  }, {
    subject: 'Physical',
    point: 8,
  }]
}]
```

How I can get min/max/avg of only Math's point

I tried get avg of Math's point `{ $avg: '$result.0.point'}` or `{ $avg: '$result.point'}` it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregations

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  "$unwind": "$results" },
  {  $match: { "results.subject": "Math" } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "avg": { "$avg": "$results.point" },
      "min": { "$min": "$results.point" },
      "max": { "$max": "$results.point" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGqPJwDpu0v)**